# how to get the id of the current image shown on viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, drawable

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                //Write fileObject tag = imageView.getTag();                  

                //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.c);

            Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),v.getResources().getResourceName((Integer)v.getTag()));


                String filename = "bitmap.png";
                FileOutputStream stream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                //Cleanup
                stream.close();
                bmp.recycle();
```

i want to add the image id from viewPager instead of the R.drawable.img1, any1 please any help?
i have edited my question, instaed of getting image from drawable i need to get ithe current image on viewPager. how do i do it?

Comment: explain more please.

Comment: Here you will find what you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015801/get-current-id-of-image-which-is-showing-on-view-pager

Comment: http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/

Comment: @MatanDahan this does not help i wanna get the current image shown on ViewPager and convert it to bitmap

Comment: you can get current position of `viewPager` with `mViewPager.getCurrentItemPosition();`, then get your image with this position form list or db or any other way that you set to your `viewPager` adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution to this

`Bitmap bmp=getBitmapFromView(viewPager.getChildAt(1));`

i got my solution with this, thanks for all your feedbacks

Comment: sorry for the late reply, getbitmap from view is the function u use to get the decoded image from ur viewPager as it was required in my application search it on google u will get better explanations

Answer (score 0):

View Pager must be having an adapter. In getView method, set position as tag to the imageviews. Then for each positions , access the imageviews as per requirement.

Comment: i use only one image view so how i tell my image view to get that current id and pass it on for sharing, i mean it what i wanna do, share the current image on fb , i just cant seem to be able to get the current image id

Comment: Have you set an adapter to the view pager?

Comment: yes i have set the adapter and m loading images from drawable into a viewPager

Comment: In getView method you have to set the id of the imageView. Then set tag to the imageview as :- imageView.setTag(position) , where position is the current position of the adapter. Then , perform getTag to get the position and fetch the drawable/image bitmap as per requirement.

Comment: i have set the tag for position and i use this tag for other functions in my code, but how do i convert the current image shown on the viewPager to bitmap, all images are initially in drawable the user sees one image and shares it, so i need to convert it to bitmap, but decodeResources() takes only resourceId so how do i get the id???

Comment: that is i want the id not the position, please help                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.c);              instead of r.drawable.blahblah, i want to put the current image id

Comment: First create a temporary imageView as :-
ImageView tempImg = (ImageView)view.findViewWithTag(position);
and then,
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)tempImg.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Comment: m getting a null pointer exception it seems i cant get the id

Comment: You are setting the tag-position only for imageview or for some other widgets also?

Comment: Also , you need to access it as view.findViewByTag , where view = the layout inflated in the adapter.

Comment: no under        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) i have included   imageView.setTag("myview" + position);

Comment: While fetching , please check if you are using "myview" + position as your tag? Otherwise it would not work. Also I would suggest you to Log the position , to check whether you are obtaining the correct position or not.

Comment: APrupa i have acessed it correctly as u said from my button click Listener and somehow i get an npe when i click on this share button

Comment: this share button is present with the same layout ie same parent view where image is present? Or image is in inflated view , and button is in some other view?

Comment: that is while fetching the image in the button click event ryt? n there is an issue wen i use position in my button click event position variable cannot be resolved, i put my buttons in OnCreateBundle() and the imageAdapter is in a different class

Comment: yes all the buttons are in the same layout as the viewPager where the images are to shown

Comment: Yes, I guessed this only !! That's why they don't have any relation with each other and getting npe !! When you are clicking the button to fetch the bitmap , you have to get the position , otherwise it's difficult... also you must have the access of the imageview to get the tags and access it.

Comment: so we are back to square one, how do i get this position m going crazy